# using a loop to plot multiple boxplots in ggplot2, long dataframe

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, ggplot2

here's my data:

`head(df)`

```
  FY      Analyte Value
  <fct>   <fct>   <dbl>
1 2007-08 CONF(G) 634  
2 2007-08 PH(G)     7.8
3 2007-08 TEMP(G)  24.8
4 2007-08 UHS(G)    2.5
5 2007-08 FC(G)     0.5
6 2007-08 CBOD(C)   1
```

My dataset is a long df, spanning 10 years. I want to create multiple ggplots (of each `Analyte`) where the x axis is `FY` (financial year) and the y axis is `Value`. Ideally the Y axis title would also change based on the variable being plotted.

I've seen a few reproducible chunks of code in my search to do this but none of them seem to apply to a long dataframe (where I want to loop through each level of the `Analyte` variable). I also want it to save to my working directory (possibly using the `png` and `dev.off()` functions).

Anyone know a solution?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the data for each `Analyte` and use `map` to save the plot as separate image.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  group_split(Analyte) %>%
  map(~{
    analyte_name <- .$Analyte[1]
    tmp <- ggplot(., aes(FY, Value)) + geom_boxplot() + ggtitle(analyte_name)
    ggsave(paste0(analyte_name, '.png'), tmp)
  })
```